# Passing blocks with unknown signatures as parameters in objective c

Tags: objective-c, graph, objective-c-blocks

I'm making a graph, and I want to make a system for specifying the conditions to transition between nodes along an edge. I am unsure of what the method signature should look like, since different transitions will have different parameters.

So the 2 functions of interest are these:

```
-addEdge(NSString* firstState, NSString* secondState,NSString* edgeName, block (?))

-(bool)transition(NSString* edgeName, parameters (?) ... )
```

addEdge() passes in a block that defines the transition condition between firstState and secondState, and gives it a name.

transition() takes in a list of parameters and applies them to the block associated with the edge name.

What should the method signatures look like, in this case?

Comment: Is `parameters` an array? How is `block` declared?

Comment: So, that is what I am wondering; I want block to take in arbitrary parameters that is presumably applicable to the specific edge. Something like [this](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/variable-arguments-varargs-in-objective-c/). 

I am unsure of what the declarations should look like to achieve this behaviour

Comment: Declaring the block to take variable arguments is the easy part. _Using_ variable arguments is hard. http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/variable-arguments-varargs-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks *can* accept variable arguments though accepting an `NSArray` is arguably simpler.

```
typedef void(^VarArgsBlock)(int argumentLength, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a block with arbitrary parameters. But you always can add **id** parameter, which is whatever you want. It could be **NSArray** or object of some specific class that you've define, anything you want. Hence you don't need any **varargs**.